# Something is modifying my iptable, can it be traced?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, ufw, forwarding, iptables-persistent

I've got the following command in my iptable: `-A FORWARD -o enp0s3 -j ACCEPT`
That somebody doesn't like, because after 2 reboots, it's gone from the iptable...

I've got *iptables-persistent*
installed, and running ufw (some says it conflicts, but it has worked before)

Well, I'm adding the command, saving, rebooting, and it works, then I'm rebooting again, and it works, then I'm rebooting again, and NOW suddenly it's not working anymore, and the `-A FORWARD -o enp0s3 -j ACCEPT` command in the iptable has been removed.
I've even tried to shutdown instead of rebooting, but the same result.

So my question is, is there anyway to "see" why this is happening, and what's doing it?

I've recently installed apache2 and certbot, and it's after this I discovered this issue, but I have no idea how to fix this..

edit: An interesting development has occurred, I'm using the  `iptables-save > /tmp/iptables.txt` command to get the table, and in that table, the forward command is missing, but when I looked directly into the rules.v4 file, and there the command still exists..

edit:
from my rules file:

```
*filter
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A FORWARD -o enp0s3 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
```

Comment: I was thinking about a temporary patch, setting up an systemd.service to add the code manually, but how do I tell it to run last (after the iptable and ufw are done with their stuff)  after=last?

Comment: One trick that may or may not work is to rename the `iptables` binary (e.g. to `iptables.orig`), and replace it with a script that logs calling information (parent PID etc.), and then calls `iptables.orig`. That won't work if the culprit is making the change isn't calling `iptables`.

Comment: @dirkt sounds like an idea, however that's beyond my knowledge..

Comment: *I've got the following command in my iptable: -A FORWARD -o enp0s3 -j ACCEPT* Where did you put it? Or are you running it by hand?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani updated the question with the requested information.